# Binding dictionary to combobox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, combobox

I have this in Load of my form which contains combobox (cmbTip)

```
EventTypeRepository tip = new EventTypeRepository();
cmbTip.DataSource = new BindingSource(tip.FindAll(), null);
cmbTip.DisplayMember = "Value";
cmbTip.ValueMember = "Key";
```

(FindAll() is a method in EventTypeRepository which returns Dictionary(string, EventType>))
For some reason this displays MyProject.Model.EventType as all combobox items. I even added:

```
public string toString()
{
     return _name + "(" + _id + ")";
}
```

in my EventType class, but it stills displays names as MyProject.Model.EventType (there are as many items as there are event types, so I think it works fine expect for displaying names). I have no idea how to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *override* `ToString` method (keep in mind C# is case-sensitive language):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0}({1})", _name, _id);
}
```

Also it's better to set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` before you set DataSource.

Comment: Lol that was easy :D Thanks for the fast help!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever find your self in a situation where you can't [override ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23983270/80274), another option is to use the [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format.aspx) event built in to the combo box. First you must set [`FormattingEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.formattingenabled.aspx) to `true` on the combo box, then subscribe to the `Format` event and use code similar to the following.

```
private void cmbTip_Format(Object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e) 
{
    var item = (EventType) e.ListItem;
    e.Value = String.Format("{0}({1})", Name, Id);
}
```

This assumes that `_name` and `_id` have corresponding public properties `Name` and `Id`.